# How do I calculate the feature scaling in Viola Jones algorithm?

Tags: viola-jones

I'm confused about how to calculate feature scaling in Viola Jones algorithm. For example in ["An Analysis of the Viola-Jones Face Detection Algorithm"](http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2014/104/article.pdf) of Yi-Qing Wang, he proposed the following for feature type "a":

1. set the original feature support size a ← 2wh
2. i <- Jie/24K, j <- Jje/24K, h <- Jhe/24K where JzK defines the nearest integer to z ∈ R+
3. w <- max{κ ∈ N : κ ≤ J1 + 2we/24K/2, 2κ ≤ e − j + 1}
4. compute the sum S1 of the pixels in [i, i + h − 1] × [j, j + w − 1]
5. compute the sum S2 of the pixels in [i, i + h − 1] × [j + w, j + 2w − 1]
6. return the scaled feature ((S1−S2)a)/2wh

In this case, I don't understand how to calculate "w" (line 3). Do you know another way of to calculate feature scaling?

On the other hand, we know that an strong classifier have weak classifiers, a polarity and a threshold. The weak classifiers depends of features. When we scale a feature, is there any a change in its threshold?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on math.stackexchange.com or something similar. This is not really a coding question.